# A second cohomology class associated to a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, cohomology, differential-operators, characteristic-classes

Let  $(M,g)$  be  a  Riemannian  manifold of  dimension at  least $4$.

We  consider  the  differential operator  $$D:\Gamma(TM)\to  \Gamma (TM)$$

with $$D(X)=\nabla \circ  Div(X)$$.

The  principal  symbol $\delta (D): \pi^* TM \to \pi^* TM$, as  a  bundle morphism,  has   constant fiber wise  rank  $1$  where  $\pi$  is  the  natural projection from the  unit  cotangent  bundle  $S^*(M)$  to  $M$. So the  image  of  this  bundle  morphism is  a  line  bundle  over $S^*(M)$. The  first  Chern  class of the  complexification of  this  line  bundle determines  a  cohomology  class  in $H^2(S^*M)\simeq H^2 (M)$. So  we  obtain a cohomology  class  $\lambda(M) \in H^2 (M)$.

> Does  this cohomology  class have  an  alternative formulation?Is there  a  name  for this  cohomology class? In dimension $4$,  does  $\int_M  \lambda(M) \wedge \lambda (M) $  depend  on the  Riemanian  metric  $g$ on $M$?

The  motivation for  this  question is  the  following:

I  was  thinking  to  find  a concept   weaker than  ellipticity  of  differential operators. Then I consider the  condition that  the  symbol  has  constant  rank  for  all fibers.(The  full rank  is  the  same  as  elliptic concept). The  only  example  I found  was  the  above  differential operator.

> What  are  some  other  examples  of  this  type:i.e the  symbol of  our differential operator is  not invertible  but  has  constant  fiber  wise  rank?
>   Are there some  theories  which  consider this  generalized elliptic  operators?

Comment: How do you get the isomorphism $H^2(SM)\simeq H^2(M)$?

Comment: @Omar  If  I  would  be  correct, the isomorphism comes  from $H^*(SM)\simeq H^*(M) \otimes H^*(S^{n-1})$. Now  I revise the  question assuming that  $M$  is  at  least $4$  dimensional.

Comment: @AliTaghavi That isomorphism doesn't hold in general eg if M is a 2-sphere. Perhaps you mean to say that the isomorphism $H^2(SM) \simeq H^2(M)$ comes from the Gysin sequence if $n$ is at least $4$.

Comment: @DannyRuberman  Dear Prof. Ruberman. Thank you very much for this very helpfull comment. I was thinking for a possible fiber bundle analogy of Kuneth formula  or for the application of Leary Hirsch Theorem for this spher bundle. I was not aware og Gysin sequence. Thanks for informing me of this sequence.

Comment: @AliTaghavi The Leray Hirsch theorem has a hypothesis that there be a cohomology class on the sphere bu Nell that restricts nontrivially to the sphere fiber. This is more or less the same as saying that the Euler class vanishes. You can find the Gysin sequence I n Milnor -Stasheff; it's the long exact sequence for the pair (E,S) together with the Thom isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to sign, the principal symbol of the operator in question is the projection onto the tautological line bundle in $\pi^*TM$. To see this, identify $TM$ with $T^*M$ using the Riemannian metric, and compute the symbol at $w\in S(TM)$. The symbol of the divergence at $w$ is $\langle-,w\rangle$. The symbol of the gradient is $w$ itself. The composition is the projection onto the trivial real line bundle $L\subset\pi^*TM$ over $S(TM)$ that is spanned by $w$ at $w\in S(TM)$. All characteristic classes of $L$ vanish.

A first order with constant rank symbol, extending your example, would be the total differential $d\colon\Omega^\bullet(M)\to\Omega^\bullet(M)$. If $M$ is a surface, it is not hard to see that the symbol class becomes trivial over $S(TM)$.

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer. I understand your answer via this example: The linear map$ \begin{pmatrix}  { \epsilon_1}^2& \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 \\  \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2&   {\epsilon_2}^2 \end{pmatrix}$ is a (not necessarily orthonormal) idempotent whose image is the span of $(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$, an element of tautological bundle. But just a question: How does a single vector field is an example of the  constant rank situation? For example $\partial_x$ with symbol $\epsilon_1$ does not satisfy the rank 1 condition. Right?  thanks  for introducing CR  geometry.

Comment: You are right. Maybe the second part of my answer is rubbish.

Comment: Note that in classical index theory, the symbol is used to create a compactly supported symbol class on $T^*M$. Compact support is important to treat the symbol in $K$-theory. But for this, one needs the symbol to be invertible outside a compact subset in $T^*M$. For your operators, you would need in addition a way to deal with kernel and cokernel of the symbol in order to define a topological index.